# Serve multiple PayPal sellers from the same website

Tags: google-app-engine, paypal, express-checkout

I have a website that does ticket sales. This website uses PayPal to process the payments. More specifically, I am using ExpressCheckout to process payments.

I have two sellers right now, and I cannot get them to both work at the same time.

Their sites are:
myapp.appspot.com/SellerA
myapp.appspot.com/SellerB

I have separate PayPal signature credentials for each seller in different config files:

```
acct1.UserName = sellera_api1.comcast.net
acct1.Password = <passwordA>
acct1.Signature = <signatureA>

acct1.UserName = sellerb_api1.comcast.net
acct1.Password = <passwordB>
acct1.Signature = <signatureB>
```

Here is the frustrating workflow that I am encountering:
1) Seller A works just fine, Seller B gets this error:

com.paypal.exception.InvalidCredentialException: Invalid userIdsellerb_api1.comcast.net

2) request new signature credentials for seller B and paste them into seller B's config file

3) Seller B works just fine, Seller A gets this error:

com.paypal.exception.InvalidCredentialException: Invalid userIdsellera_api1.comcast.net

4) request new signature credentials for seller A and paste them into seller A's config file

5) back to step 1

Any idea what could be happening here and how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to set them as two different accounts (like below) so that you make different API calls based on API user.

```
acct1.Username = sellera_api1.comcast.net
acct2.Username = sellerb_api1.comcast.net
```

Then you could call

```
setExpressCheckout(SetExpressCheckoutReq setExpressCheckoutReq, String apiUsername)
```

This probably not the best way to solve it and so I am very interested to see other solutions.

Comment: This read like an answer, but then you ask for another solution? This threw me off and I don't think this should be there in an answer.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion! But clearly that's my answer as I am in similar situation and figured it through PayPal SDK. But curious about any other solutions, specially the question was from last year & must have be solved by now.

Comment: Ok, I changed the last sentence so your intention is a little clearer. If you don't like it, you can revert to an earlier version from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28332421/revisions).